# Langmuir output in Lyx?

Tags: lyx, achemso

I have achemso package installed for Lyx, how do I select the Langmuir layout which is langd5 to get the desired output ?

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=27376)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Document --> Settings --> Document class. Select *American Chemical Society (ACS)* as the class, and add `journal=langd5` to the *Custom* options. For a twocolumn document, add `layout=twocolumn` as well.

```
journal=langd5,layout=twocolumn
```

Do not select *Two column document* in the *Text layout* tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but if I select the two column option from the Text Layout then it doesn't preserve the positions of the images. I have uploaded the first page here, http://dropcanvas.com/qp10s

Comment: @Curious Use `layout=twocolumn` instead, see updated answer.

Comment: I get errors with two column :  \begin{mcitethebibliography}{38}
                                    
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Comment: and how to remove the email before the abstract. Another error is Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 86 of file ACS.aux. I don't get these when single column style is selected.

Comment: I have no idea about those things. I recommend asking separate questions about them. When you do, create a minimal example (a small file that demonstrates the problem), open the `.lyx` file in a text editor and copy-paste the entire file into your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I found that the problem is with the bibliography.